# docker restart,exit command, reboot the host machine

Tags: linux, docker

I pulled the image from public repo. The problem is when I attach and exit out of the container, it will reboot the host machine also. I'm not sure what is the problem here.

**Logs : [ when restart the container]**

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker restart 714fed06f99f
714fed06f99f
[root@localhost ~]# Write failed: Broken pipe

 <-= DISCONNECTED (PRESS <ENTER> TO RECONNECT) (Fri Feb 20 16:44:35 2015)
```

**Another Log: [ when run the "exit" command]**

```
[root@4e53f038d880 ~]# exit
exit
Write failed: Broken pipe

 <-= DISCONNECTED (PRESS <ENTER> TO RECONNECT) (Fri Feb 20 16:48:42 2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the container stops when you exit from attach?

This will happen, as you're "attaching" to the main process. If you send the main process a `SIGKILL` (`Ctrl-c`), it will stop, causing the container to exit. You can use the special Docker code `Ctrl-p Ctrl-q` to exit the attach without stopping the container.

See http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#attach for more details.

Comment: No . it stops the entire host machine where all docker containers are running.  Do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem .?

Comment: No idea, sounds bad though. What's the image?

Comment: centos 6.5 [ 64 bit ] - Kernel verion 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.  Docker version-1.4.1

Comment: Sorry, what was the image you pulled and are trying to run?

Comment: centos:latest and centos:centos6. I tried and had a problem with both images